# Sharing Session between 2 servers

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a session created in one server from a another server. Which means i need to share session between 2 asp.net applications hosted in 2 different servers.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mode your session state is configured to SQLServer:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Comment: Is it applicable to ASP.NET 2.0 and SQLServer 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to model your session in a common database. (I believe there are some modules that will do this for you, but i can't remember the names offhand)

Store the SessionKey in a database. If your server detects a cookie with a sessionkey, then use that sessionkey to pull the data from the database (something like that).

I don't think it is possible to do it out of the box with ASP.NET. (could be wrong though!)

Answer (score 0):

Change the session state to [SqlServer Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (Database). Using [Sql Server mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) session state is preserved in database.